# Showing that closed set is the preimage of $0$ of the distance function

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. For a nonempty subset $A$ of $X$ we
>   define the real valued **distance function $\rho_A$** by $\rho_A(x) :=
>  \inf\{d(x,a) : a \in A\}$ for any $x \in X$.

Now it is quite intuitive, that $$A = \rho_A^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$$ whenever $A$ is closed. The inclusion $A \subseteq \rho_A^{-1}(\{0\})$ is trivial, but somehow I do not exactly know what to use to show the other inclusion. Any hint would be nice.

Comment: Have you tried to show that $\overline{A}=\rho_A^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: @MaikPickl I thought about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\rho_A(x) = 0$, hence 
$$ \inf_{a \in A} d(x,a) = 0 $$
By definition of the infimum, given $n \in \mathbf N$, there is $x_n \in A$ with 
$$ d(x_n,a) < \frac 1n $$
Then $x_n \to a$. As $x_n \in A$, and $A$ is closed, we have $a \in A$.

Therefore $\rho_A^{-1}(\{0\}) \subseteq A$.